# Events Manager Pro plugin and Qtranslate for location

Tags: wordpress, events, placeholder, qtranslate, qtranslate-x

I'm working on a Wordpress site with the Events Manager Pro plugin for Wordpress plugin and Qtranslate. When I use the event page the content will show in the correct language. But when I use the #_LOCATIONNAME in the Booking email template it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any type of e-mail plugin etc., you might be use it's format for email template. Like **{#_LOCATIONNAME}** with brackets etc..
or you can change proccessing priority https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71406/is-there-a-flowchart-for-wordpress-loading-sequence